# SQL Server Grant execute on all stored procedures without ddl permissions

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2008-r2, sql-server-2012, security, permissions

I have some users in my database. They are member of db_datareader. They now also need to have execute permissions on stored procedures. I was just wondering what would happen if one of the stored procedures issue DDL? Would they be able to make schema changes to tables, drop etc. through that stored procedure?

Thank you

Answer (score 4, accepted):

NO, With just `Execute` permission doesn't allow a user to execute a stored procedure successfully if it contains some DDL (`CREATE, ALTER, DROP, TRUNCATE, RENAME`) statements.

Answer (score 4):

Use [module signing](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms345102(v=sql.105).aspx). Sign your procedures with a certificate and then grant the required permissions to a certificate-derived user. The link contains a full example.